# Deleted classes.jar file from Android Studio build-cache

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    v=this.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv=(ListView)v;
    adp=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,str);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);

}
```

The above code is showing me an error because I have permanently deleted classes.jar file in users->.android->build-cache folder

What should I do now?

Comment: Try `File-> Invalidate caches/Restart`

Comment: I did it but still I'm getting problem

Comment: I have deleted the classes.jar file which is present under this path  *android/build-cache/some_random_folder_name/output/jars/classes.jar*

Comment: I found the solution for the above problem.

Comment: I completely removed Android Studio setup from my system with all supporting directories in user files

Comment: Glad that you figured out